# Bulk-tagging: [matrix]

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to propose a [matrix](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) tag, because they constitute a class of problems that have much in common with each other.

There are currently [128 relevant questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+matrix+-%5Bmatrix%5D).  Is there a way to tag them in bulk?  Also, can they be tagged without swamping the front page with matrix-related questions?

Comment: Good idea.  I'm not sure how this works, but it would be *much* better than covering the front page several times over.

Comment: Based on [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118937/how-to-notify-a-moderator-of-list-of-question-where-a-bulk-retagging-would-be-ap), it seems that not even moderators can do this.  Each question would have to be retagged manually.  If this is still necessary, then I *suppose* this can be done when there are no new questions on the front page.  I can do this if there is such a time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Jamal's finding that there is [no bulk retagging feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118942), I propose that we just tag a few of the newer matrix-related questions for now to build a critical mass. Then do others opportunistically if they ever happen to appear on the front page or need editing for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion I have in mind is to retag a certain number of these questions over some period of time.  For instance... five or ten questions per day, throughout the day.  Something like that.  This will eventually empty that list of 128, and we won't need to swamp the front page.

At the same time, we can edit/close/delete any questions as needed.

For right now, we can start with the unanswered questions.  There are [only 16](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+matrix+-%5Bmatrix%5D+answers%3A0), so that can be done in a minute.  Then we can move onto the rest of the list, possibly following the suggestion mentioned above.